# Calculating homology group of fiber bundle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fiber-bundles

I'm attempting to calculate the homology groups of this space and need some help.

Let $B$ be a 2-dimensional disk and $A$ a discrete set in its interior. Then let’s say we have a fiber bundle $X$ of a space (in this case a closed compact surface) over $B-A$. How would I go about calculating homology groups of the space $X$ where we identify all the holes in the bundle as one point? I wanted to use the face that it’s a fiber bundle, but at the point I quotient out it isn’t a bundle.

I’m also pretty new to algebraic topology generally. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have to say, I find your question is unclear. It seems that your setup is that you have a fiber bundle $p: X\to B-A$, where  $X$ is a closed surface (compact is redundant). But there are no such fiber bundles! Maybe you mean something else and fibers of your bundle are closed surfaces? The next sentence "How would I ..." I could not understand at all. In general, computing homology of fiber bundles is difficult and requires spectral sequences. But, if your base is effectively a graph (since $B-A$ is h.e. to a graph), then the computation is simpler.

Comment: I’m sorry for the confusion. I was labelling the bundle as $X$. So the fibers are a closed surface $F$ and the bundle is over a punctured disk. 

I haven’t read about spectral sequences yet, but they sound useful.

Comment: I suggest, you modify your question to make it clearer. How much Algebraic Topology do you know? For instance, do you know the Mayer-Vietoris exact sequence? For instance, if you have a surface bundle over circle, do you know how to compute homogy of the total space? If you do, I can explain how to compute homology groups in your setting.